# How to test the layout of a custom UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I have a test class created for a custom cell I have created. The cell is fairly complex, has several different labels and images that are auto-layout constrained to the cell's bounds, and I want to test that setting long text for certain labels doesn't make the label go past the bounds of the cell. 
Essentially, I want to run the following line:

```
XCTAssertLessThanOrEqual(cell.textLabel!.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.width, "text label width should be less than cell's frame")
```

to make sure that my custom textLabel doesn't go past the bounds. The problem I'm having, though, is I don't know how to mock the custom cell, `cell` above. Do I need to create a mock table view and populate that with mock data to then get a mock cell, or is there a way to create an instance of a custom subclass of a `UITableViewCell` and test the layout of that immediately?

Answer (score 3):

The Tests could look like this (Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832276/tests-for-custom-uitableviewcell-cellforrowatindexpath-crashes-with-nil-outlets)).

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

class MainViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var controller: MainViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        controller = MainViewController()
        controller.view.description
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testTableViewOutlet() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(controller.tableView)
    }

    func testTableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath() {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

        let cell = controller.tableView(controller.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        XCTAssertEqual(cell.countryLabel.text!, "USA")
        XCTAssertEqual(cell.capitalLabel.text!, "Washington, D.C.")
    }
}
```

Comment: not a great way to test this way...i think should pass a mock tableview

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃 hmmm I think so . can you share Great way doing this things